# bottom: 0 vs vertical-align: bottom

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between `vertical-align: bottom` and `bottom: 0` (or any other direction) selectors. What is the better way to put elements to the edges of the screen?

Comment: I wouldn't call any difference because they are completely different, not related in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`vertical-align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) refers to the y-axis alignment of contents of inline level elements or to table cell contents.

[`bottom`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-bottom) is a CSS property used in the vertical alignment of positioned elements and has no effect on non-positioned elements.

- when `position` value is set to `relative`, the element will use itself as reference.
- when `position` value is set to anything else (except `static`, of course), the element will use its closest positioned ancestor (for `absolute` and `sticky`) or its closest viewport (for `fixed`) as reference.

Therefore, a comparison between the two cannot be made generically, as they serve different purposes, even if they can both be used to achieve a subset of display alterations to an element.

In other words, before anyone can answer the question: *"What's better?"*, you have to define what *"better"* means in your case. What are the requirements?

---

Furthermore, it is important to note `bottom` only affects the composite layer, without affecting Style, Layout and Paint layers.
This becomes important when you want to modify the rendered position of an element without triggering redraw on subsequent elements in DOM.
Adjusting `bottom` value achieves this, therefore making it a good candidate for animations (because it doesn't trigger layout redraws after each animation frame).
But, let it be said an even more performant candidate is `transform` and, whenever possible, you should use `transform` animations over `bottom` animations.

Answer (score 1):

```css
    *{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
    }

    .name{
       background:red;
       height:200px;
       width:200px;
       position:relative;


          
    }
    h2{
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align:bottom;
background:white;
    }
    .second {
       height: 100px;
       
    }
    .third{
       position:absolute;
       bottom:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="name">
       <h2>bottom</h2>
       <h2 class="second">inline</h2>
       <h2 class="third">bottom</h2>
     </div>
```

- bottom:0 with absolute position: place element to bottom of his parent! work with any display
- vertical-align:bottom: align inline elements to bottom of the line! verical-align work with inline elements (display:inline,inline-block..)!